# For i in loop with printf error

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in {1..3}
do
cp dummy.dat dummy/dummy.`printf "%04d%s_shp" ${i}`

done
```

and the

```
error: printf: 9: {1..3}: expected numeric value
```

If I type:

```
for i in  0 2 3
```

The script is working.

What is wrong with my script on the top? Or anyone a solution?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not necessary bash.

Comment: (You should try it with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line.)

Comment: On Ubuntu and I believe Debian systems #!/bin/sh is not necessarily bash. If you want bash, you have to explicitly request it like so #!/bin/bash. On Red Hat systems, #!/bin/sh points to bash.

Comment: Your shell *almost certainly* supports `$()`. Please use that form [instead of backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 3):

Your `/bin/sh` doesn't support `{1..3}` which is a bash extension. You can either:

1. Use `#!/bin/bash` to ensure the script is always run with bash.
2. Use `$(seq 1 3)` which is a POSIX-compliant replacement which will supposedly work with all shells.

Comment: Not all shells support that POSIXy replacement either.

Comment: `seq` is *not* POSIX.  (At least, it's not listed at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Comment: @DonalFellows: It's not the shell, it's the OS or distribution. `seq` is an external utility, on some systems it's not available, but `jot` is.

Comment: @Dennis What I can say for sure is that it didn't work when I tried it. :-) Nor did I find anything that looked vaguely like it in the bash manpage.

Comment: @DonalFellows: `seq` is an external utility - you won't find those in the Bash man page - see `man seq` or `man jot`. Your system should have one or the other of `/usr/bin/seq` or `/usr/bin/jot`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: you are right indeed. I guess then the simplest solution would be to inline `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf "%04d%s_shp" ${i}
        ^   ^
        1   2
```

`printf` expects *two* values.

The `%04d` means it wants a number (which will be given 4 spaces and padded with leading zeros), the `%s` means it expects to get a string value. You are only supplying  one value, `i`, to `printf`

Only a guess, but did you mean perhaps just:

```
printf "%04d_shp" ${i}
```

i.e., without the `s%` ?

Comment: Although that is an error indeed, it doesn't cause that message. AFAICS `printf` will just treat the missing argument as an empty string.

Comment: @MichałGórny I didn't know that `printf` under the shell is so forgiving (no access to machine right now to play around with it) .. certainly other languages take a dim view of this. Thanks for the comment, noted for future exploration.

Comment: @craphunter Just a friendly note, if this solved your problem, please consider ccepting this answer - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The literal `{1..3}` is not numeric. It has numbers in it, but the shell doesn't (necessarily) interpret it as a range in a `for`; you have to write it out in full (or use a `while` loop and some expression calculation).

Comment: With the appropriate version of bash, `{1..3}` expands to `1 2 3`, so the for loop does iterate through the numeric values.

Comment: @Dennis Fair enough; updated. It's still the problem though: in this case, it's not expanded _for whatever reason_, and that's the only way such code could cause that error message at that place.